# Keep some information between different "new" forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a form where the user can choose options from a lot of select boxes. The form is used to register several items from an RSS feed. The user fills in the form, clicks create and is presented with the same form for the next item in the list.

Sometimes, the same options are valid for several items in the list, and I would like to be able to save some of the selections done so the user doesn't have to make the same selection for the next items.

What is the best way of doing this? I've identified four ways of doing it:

### Sessions

Just keep the values in the session hash. This will of course work and is very simple, but I have some undefined feeling that it is a bad idea. It will also not work if the user is using the form from different tabs in the browser.

### Cookies

Basically the same as keeping them in the session, I think.

### Profile

Can't be done in this case I believe, since profiles are shared between several users.

### Database

The most complex way I've come up with is to keep the information in the database and use a query parameter to keep track of which information should be used. This is probably overkill, but in some ways the best way to me. I don't like the idea of keeping this kind of state in session or cookies.

Am I missing some way? Or something?

Answer (score 0):

If after filling first form, some data is saved to db (object is created) then you can use this data from db to fill up new form.

If after filling first form, nothing is saved to db, then you can create in memory some objects based on params from previous post and based on this (on just on `params`) you can prepare new form. But of course data from previous form should be added as hidden fields in second form.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I want to create several separate objects, but most of the information is reused for the next object from the feed.

Comment: If I misunderstod you, then probably I still don't understand you. If you create several objects, then each of them is saved in db, so you can read from them and based on this fill new form. Where is your problem here?